# StormCrawler: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

We are consistently getting the following error when we increase either the number of threads or the number of executors for Fetcher bolt.

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:286) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:220) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol.getProtocolOutput(HttpProtocol.java:206) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

Is this due to a resource leak or some hard limit on the size of the http thread pool? If it is about the thread pool, is there any way to increase the pool size?

Comment: which version of StormCrawler are you using? How many threads per FetcherBolt and executors? Thanks

Comment: We are using 1.7, we are using 200 threads per fethcer bolt. Since we are running storm on very large instances, we would want to run 4 fether bolts per instance.

Comment: then have more workers per instance and one fetcher bolt per worker. There is no gain from having multiple FetcherBolts for a single worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a max number of connections for the pool set in [HttpProtocol](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/protocol/httpclient/HttpProtocol.java#L93), which is the number of threads used (fetcher.threads.number). Since the pool is static, it is used by all the executors on the same worker. I'd recommend that you use one FetcherBolt instance per worker, it will then be the same value as fetcher.threads.number and you won't have this problem.

Alternatively, you could give the [okhttp protocol](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/protocol/okhttp/HttpProtocol.java) a try. It is more robust for open and large-scale crawls. See [WIKI page on protocols](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Protocols) for a feature comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your response Julien. Will try okhttp protocol. Should we have a common thread pool per fetcher bolt rather than per worker? That way users can have finer control on fetcher bolts. Fetching robots.txt also uses threads from thread pool.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer above as useful or accepted. See comment above, have multiple workers per machine and as many FetcherBolts